# Set Actionbar overlay from SherlockFragment

Tags: android, actionbarsherlock, fragment, overlay

I want to set `ActionbarOverlay` feature from within my `SherlockFragment` class.
Can any one please tell me, how can I do this?

I've tried by adding line `getSherlockActivity().requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_ACTION_MODE_OVERLAY);` in `OnCreateView` method.

But it gives me **Error:**

```
04-17 12:19:35.789: E/AndroidRuntime(844): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
04-17 12:19:35.789: E/AndroidRuntime(844): android.util.AndroidRuntimeException: requestFeature() must be called before adding content
04-17 12:19:35.789: E/AndroidRuntime(844):  at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow.requestFeature(PhoneWindow.java:210)
04-17 12:19:35.789: E/AndroidRuntime(844):  at com.oceans.sherelock.internal.ActionBarSherlockNative.requestFeature(ActionBarSherlockNative.java:97)
04-17 12:19:35.789: E/AndroidRuntime(844):  at com.oceans.sherelock.app.SherlockFragmentActivity.requestWindowFeature(SherlockFragmentActivity.java:276)
04-17 12:19:35.789: E/AndroidRuntime(844):  at com.wallpapermaker.keepcalm.UserProfile_NoBoringFragment.onCreateView(UserProfile_NoBoringFragment.java:92)
04-17 12:19:35.789: E/AndroidRuntime(844):  at android.support.v4.app.Fragment.performCreateView(Fragment.java:1500)
04-17 12:19:35.789: E/AndroidRuntime(844):  at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.moveToState(FragmentManager.java:938)
04-17 12:19:35.789: E/AndroidRuntime(844):  at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.moveToState(FragmentManager.java:1115)
04-17 12:19:35.789: E/AndroidRuntime(844):  at android.support.v4.app.BackStackRecord.run(BackStackRecord.java:682)
04-17 12:19:35.789: E/AndroidRuntime(844):  at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.execPendingActions(FragmentManager.java:1478)
04-17 12:19:35.789: E/AndroidRuntime(844):  at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl$1.run(FragmentManager.java:446)
04-17 12:19:35.789: E/AndroidRuntime(844):  at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:605)
04-17 12:19:35.789: E/AndroidRuntime(844):  at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:92)
04-17 12:19:35.789: E/AndroidRuntime(844):  at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
04-17 12:19:35.789: E/AndroidRuntime(844):  at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4424)
04-17 12:19:35.789: E/AndroidRuntime(844):  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
04-17 12:19:35.789: E/AndroidRuntime(844):  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
04-17 12:19:35.789: E/AndroidRuntime(844):  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:784)
04-17 12:19:35.789: E/AndroidRuntime(844):  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:551)
04-17 12:19:35.789: E/AndroidRuntime(844):  at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

**P.S.** I can't set it from within `Activity` because I don't want overlay feature to be enabled for other Fragments in my Activity.

Answer (score 0):

You Must Call before setContent called in your activity

```
getSherlockActivity().requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_ACTION_MODE_OVERLAY);
```

put this before adding content view in your activity.

i hope it helps.

***UPDATE***

then extends first SherlockFragment in your Fragment
then put code in OnCreate method of Activity before calling setContentView method.

```
getSherlock().requestFeature(Window.FEATURE_ACTION_MODE_OVERLAY);
```

sorry my fault
check update again.

Comment: I know i have to put this before setContent in `Activity` but I am asking about `Fragment`.

Comment: I tried with your updated solution but this is also giving me the same error.

Comment: I can't set it from within Activity because I don't want overlay feature to be enabled for other Fragments in my Activity.